# Issue with Rails 3 array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails 3 app, every User's profile has an array that I want to add to. The items are unique, but are added to each Profile in one of two categories. What I'm having trouble with however is linking the profile_item to the item through their IDs.

**profile.rb Model:**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

  has_many :profile_todos
  has_many :todos, :through => :profile_todos

  def add_todo_inside_item(item)
    self.profile_todos.build :category => 'inside'
  end

  def add_todo_outside_item(item)
    self.profile_todos.build :category => 'outside'
  end
end
```

**todo.rb Model:**

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
end
```

**profile_todo.rb Model:**

```
class ProfileTodo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :todo
end
```

**`Todo.new` gives the following:**

```
>> Todo.new
=> #<Todo id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

**`ProfileTodo.new` gives the following:**

```
>> ProfileTodo.new
=> #<ProfileTodo id: nil, category: nil, profile_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

**I'm calling the `profile_todos` in my profiles using:**

```
<div id="todosheader">
  <p><%= @profile.first_name %>&nbsp;has&nbsp;<%= pluralize(@profile.profile_todos.count, 'todo') %>.</p>
</div>
<div id="todo-list">
  <div class="todos_inside">
    <h4>Inside&nbsp;(<%= @profile.profile_todos(:category => "inside").count %>)</h4>
    <p><%= @profile.profile_todos(:category => "outside") %></p>
  </div>
  <div class="todos_outside">
    <h4>Outside&nbsp;(<%= @profile.profile_todos(:category => "outside").count %>)</h4>
    <p><%= @profile.profile_todos(:category => "outside") %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I add a `todo` to the profile where the `Todo` `:name` is added with a given `:category` to the Profile? Right now calling `@profile.profile_todos` returns an empty array.

Let's say I have a Todo of "Test", with an ID of "1". If I try to add that `Todo` to my `profile_todos` array using `@profile.add_todo_inside_item("Test")`, I can't seem to attach the "Test" `Todo` to my `profile_todos(:category => "inside")`.

Comment: From your example it's not clear how you want to call this.. Given your code above, it doesn't make sense to call Todo.new or ProfileGoal.new and expect anything else but an empty instance.

Comment: What I want to do is have `todos` be available for all users to add to their `profile_todos`. But I want to add todos to `profile_todos` by category, either "inside" or "outside". So I want to take the :name of a `todo` (the string value), give it a category, and add it to `profile_todos`. That way I can separate profile_todos into `profile_todos(:category => "inside")` and `profile_todos(:category => "outside")`. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do here..

todos should be plural.. and you should save the parent..

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :todos

    def new_inside_todo(params)  # takes a hash of all attributes, like new()
      params.merge!( {:category => "inside"} )
      self.todos.build( params )
      self.save(:validate => false)
    end

    def new_outside_todo(params)
      params.merge!( {:category => "outside"} )
      self.todos.build( params )
      self.save(:validate => false)
    end
end

class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :profile

   # has an attribute called category

   # if Todos belong to more than one class, make the relationship polymorphic
   #     belongs_to :parent , :polymorphic => true
end
```

Comment: I just added an update to my question. I hope that gives some more insight. Thanks for the help!